# How do I write this URL in Django?

Tags: regex, django, url

```
(r'^/(?P<the_param>[a-zA-z0-9_-]+)/$','myproject.myapp.views.myview'),
```

How can I change this so that "the_param" accepts a URL(encoded) as a parameter?

So, I want to pass a URL to it.

```
mydomain.com/http%3A//google.com
```

Edit: Should I remove the regex, like this...and then it would work?

(r'^/(?P[*]?)/?$','myproject.myapp.views.myview'),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `%` and `.` to the character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_%.-]
```

**Note:** You don't need to escape special characters inside character classes because special characters lose their meaning inside character sets. The `-` if not to be used to specify a range should be escaped with a back slash or put at the beginning (for python [2.4.x](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/re-syntax.html) , [2.5.x](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/re-syntax.html), [2.6.x](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/re.html)) or at the end of the character set(python [2.7.x](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)) hence something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_%-.]` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll at least need something like:

```
(r'^the/uri/is/(?P<uri_encoded>[a-zA-Z0-9~%\._-])$', 'project.app.view'),
```

That expression should match everything described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Note that your example should be `mydomain.com/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com` (slashes should be encoded).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with:

```
(r'^(?P<url>[\w\.~_-]+)$', 'project.app.view')
```